# C# UDP Client recive too slow

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I try for communication between PLC (Electronic Device) and PC. Firewall turned off. I see received package by wireshark.

question 1: Receiving messagges is too slow, Why? it takes several time to arrive in my code. My code is below.

question 2: How can WireShark Software capture quickly this messages? How can I achive this in C#?

question 3: I have to turn off Firewall for receiving messages. But wireshark don't need turn off firewall. How can I achive this by never turn off firewall. I try basically 1 to 1 local communication.

```
    private void udpcommincate()
    {
        sock_rcv = new UdpClient(6002);
        try
        {
            sock_rcv.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }  
    }
    private void recv(IAsyncResult res)
    {
        IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 6002);
        plc_gelen = sock_rcv.EndReceive(res, ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
        flag= BitConverter.ToInt32(plc_gelen, 0);
        sock_rcv.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), null);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. For simple UDP communications you don't need all this asynchronous machinery - it takes time to post request to thread pool, dispatch the callback, etc. etc. If you want speed, just do blocking read in a loop, all in one thread.
2. and 3. Wireshark taps into special kernel interface (implemented in the [winpcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) library) that gets a copy of all packets matching given filter, often before in-kernel firewall gets its hands on them.